# OpenCV - motion detection in large video files

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have large video files (over a few GB each) that I am trying detect motion on. I am using fairly basic OpenCV code in python with ROI to detect motion in a certain area of the video only. This works absolutely fine but takes absolutely ages to process large files. Is there any way to speed things up? I am simply just checking to see which file has motion detected in it and will not be outputting a video. The moment the first motion is detected the rest of the file is not checked.

```
import sys
import cv2

video_path = “video.mp4”

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Set the first frame as the reference background
_, background = capture.read()

# Define the region of interest (ROI)
x, y, w, h = 1468, 1142, 412, 385
roi = (x, y, x + w, y + h)

while capture.isOpened():
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    # Extract the region of interest from the current frame
    frame_roi = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # Calculate the absolute difference between the ROI and the background
    diff = cv2.absdiff(background[y:y + h, x:x + w], frame_roi)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Check if motion is detected in the ROI (adjust threshold as needed)
    if cv2.countNonZero(thresh) > 75:
        print("YES")
        break

# Release the video capture object
capture.release()
```

Comment: May be it could help to redefine what 'motion' is because it could help to skip frames instead of checking them all.

Comment: background and region are defined outsize the loop, so do not crop inside the loop, crop outside the loop

Comment: @LMC The motion is to detect when an object/human/pet etc appears within a specific region

Comment: @fmw42 how would I crop the current frame from outside the loop? Can you give more guidance please?

Comment: Unless you are expecting very fast moving objects is perhaps more efficient to compare every 30 frames or more.

Comment: @LMC how could I do that efficiently? By going through and reading each frame, won’t it still be time consuming regardless of if a comparison for that frame is made or not?

Comment: reading a frame and comparing to the background could be avoided. See [here incrementing frame_id by 30 or 60](https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/introduction-to-image-analysis-for-plant-phenotyping/0/steps/305359)

Comment: @fmw42 I see *no way* to "crop outside the loop". this is processing frames of a video, not a single image. -- "running the video through ffmpeg to crop it" (if you were thinking that) may *technically* be an implementation of your suggestion but that defeats the purpose (costs extra time) and potentially degrades data quality.

Comment: @LMC seeking can be costly and not save you any time at all. further, it can be imprecise. it's a better idea to use `grab()` and `retrieve()` instead of `read()`. besides that, your suggestion does *not* "avoid" comparing to the background. it merely reduces the number of frames that are considered.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz isnt a combination of grab() and retrieve() the same as read()?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz.  Perhaps I misunderstand his code, but he shows the reading of background and a set value for the crop region, that is above the while loop to read a frame. So it looks like he reads each frame and uses the same background and crop coordinates for all frames.

Comment: @M9A and what if you *don't* combine them?